# Angularjs directive + do I need to $compile

Tags: angularjs

I'm in need of some pointers in my landingPage-builder project. (i'm currently stuck!).

The main issue is as follows:
Each element in the template (like the h1 and the paragraph) has attached a directive. What I need to get the directive to do is: create a template of HTML with some other directives attached like ng-click, ng-options etc, keep the bindings to the model intact (currently far away from working), update the model when changed.

I'm not trying to append to, or replace the element the directive is on, but make a html-template and inserting it into the DOM (almost like another view) so that the model on the left can be updated from the "settings" box on the right.

The project can be viewed here:         `http://193.107.29.196/~stian123/landingPageV3/app/#/pagebuilder/2`

You may need Allow-Control-Allow-Origin for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related

I'm a bit confused about $compile and doesn't really know when I need to use this part of the directives api.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: I looked inside your application. You are missing the whole point of data bindings and scopes. The right panel shouldn't be created on the fly each time you click on an item from the left side. I don't fully understand what you want to accomplish there but if you really take advantage of angular.js capabilities it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to dynamically create templates, some of which have Angular attributes in them, then attach them to the DOM.

First, to (hopefully) answer your question, about when to call $compile:

Whenever you load in HTML from outside Angular's template system (like trying to set $(element).html(myHtmlString)), you need to let Angular compile it before you attach it to the DOM. In other words:

```
elem.append($compile(yourHTMLString)(scope));
```

This lets Angular traverse the DOM and parse any directives and bindings and attach them to the provided scope. If you don't $compile, Angular has no idea about those intended bindings at all, the HTML is never read by Angular.

Second, I don't know how flexible you want your templates to be, but if they're relatively fixed, but with some fixed customizable options (text, color, font-size etc), you might be better off creating a directive for each 'view', with the view options bound to the scope of the directive. Then you can just change the fields on the scope of the directive in the panel on the right side, and the view will update directly. You wouldn't even have to use $compile in this case.

If you want the user to be able to manually add the template HTML code, you will have to compile the HTML as described above.